# Geometric sequence from integer and decimal parts

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

A positive number has a decimal part and an integer part.  The decimal part, the integer part, and the positive number itself form a geometric sequence.  Find this positive number.

My attempt: Let...

- d=decimal part

  i=integer part

  e=the entire number

Then $\frac{d}{i}=\frac{i}{e}$.  I also noticed $e=i+d$ so $\frac{d}{i}=\frac{i}{d+i}$.  But there are still too many variables and it seems I don't have enough information to solve this.

Comment: Note 0 < d < i < e.  Forming a geometric sequence simply means there is a $\frac di = \frac ie \implies de = i^2$ combine that with i) $e = i  + d$ and ii) $i \in \mathbb Z$ and iii) 0 \le d < 1$ and you should be able to solve.

Comment: $de = i^2$.  $d^2 + id - i^2 = 0$.$d = -i/2 + \frac{\sqrt{i^2 + 4i^2}}2=\frac 12i(\sqrt{5} -1)$.  So $0 \le d < 1$.  $i = 0 = d = e$ is a trivial answer.  $i = 1; d = \frac 12(\sqrt{5} -1)=0.61803398874989484820458683436564$ works.  if $i \ge 2$ then $d \ge \sqrt{5} -1 > 1$ so that is not possible.  We must have $e = d + i =  \frac 12(\sqrt{5} -1) + 1 = 1.61803398874989484820458683436564$ or $e = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\frac{d}{i}=\frac{i}{d+i}$, we find that $i^2-di-d^2=0$ which implies that
$$i=d\cdot \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Since $e$ is positive, $i$ can not be zero (otherwise by the above equation also $d=0$). By the same reason, $d>0$. Therefore $i$ is a positive integer and $d\in(0,1)$. Thus  we have 
$$1\leq i=d\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}<2,$$
that is $i=1$ and $d=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$. Finally
$$e=i+d=1+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
A [famous number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Clearly $d<i<e$. Let $r=\frac{i}d=\frac{e}i$, so that $i=dr$ and $e=dr^2$. As you say, $e=d+i$, so

$$dr^2=dr+d\;,$$

and we can divide through by $d$ to find that

$$r^2=r+1\;,$$

an equation that you can solve for $r$. Finally, you know that $i=dr$ must be an integer and that $0<d<1$. It’s possible to finish from here with a bit of persistence and just a little cleverness in working out what $d$ must look like if $dr$ is to be an integer. If you get completely stuck, check the spoiler-protected block below.

> Try $d=r-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By dividing the $3$ numbers in the sequence by $i$ we get another sequence satisfying the conditions: $d/i, 1, 1+d/i$. So you can assume $i = 1$ to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Nice hint!  But I'd say rather than assume $i=1$ (we could also assume $i = 2$ or $i=3$ or whatever) we could solve for $x = d/i$.  Then we have to have  $i = d/x < 1/x$.  Which as it turns out has only one possible value for $i$.